# Is it "am Nachmittag" or "um Nachmittag"?

Tags: preposition

It found, it is "am Mittag", but "um Mitternacht". So that doesn't help me.

I can find examples of both "am Nachmittag" and "um Nachmittag" on the internet.

Comment: "am Nachmittag" means the exact time, "um Nachmittag" means only a rough estimation.

Comment: @peterh: But you will use "um" for exact times: "Wir treffen uns um Viertel nach drei." is an exact time. "Um Nachmittag" sounds very strange. I wouldn't use it. In addition, "Nachmittag" is always an approximate time indication.

Comment: @clemens Well, you are right! I think "um" means a rough estimation only in space.

Comment: please give example findings of "um Nachmittag"

Comment: @peterh Wir fahren jedes Jahr um Ostern in Skiurlaub.

Comment: @userunknown Dann verstehe ich schon nichts. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is *"am Nachmittag"*, since it describes not one specific time, but a time interval.

> Am Morgen, am Mittag, am Abend
>
> Um Mitternacht (exactly 00:00), um 5 Uhr, um 12 Uhr am Mittag

I don't know where you found examples for *"um Nachmittag"*, I didn't find any. Of course, one could make a construction like

> Er kontruierte einen Satz, um "Nachmittag" nach "um" zu sagen.

but oviously this is completely different.

One could possibly also say

> Wir treffen uns so um den Nachmittag herum.

what is also a strange construction. (I am actually not sure if this is correct at all, one would use *"gegen Nachmittag"* to express this.)